# Docker memory parameter for container not working

Tags: docker, memory, wsl-2

I'm having a problem where setting the memory parameter in the docker container creation does not actually result in changing the memory limit. I'm using wsl2 on my pc, which as 32GB of RAM. For example, I run the following command,

```
$ docker run -it --memory="24g" --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/splicepath_pc,type=bind splicepath
```

Viewing `docker stats`, i see the following

[image]

I would like the limit to show 24GB instead of 15.59GB. I'm unable to manually change the memory with the sliding bar since I'm using wsl2 (see image below).

[image]

Looking online it was recommended that I change the `.wslconfig` in my file in my `%UserProfile%` directory to include the following,

```
[wsl2]
memory=28GB
```

However, this changed nothing. I've noticed the same thing happens on my mac computer but using the slider on the mac seems to fix the problem. Again, why is my docker `--memory="24g` command not working correctly and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer fixed this... lol

`free -mh` shows 24GB and `docker stats` shows 24GB.